# Hive Query - Unable to find for movies having more than 30 ratings, what is the average rating

Tags: hadoop, hiveql

I have created a table in hive using query

```
CREATE TABLE u_data (
 userid INT,
 movieid INT,
 rating INT,
 unixtime STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

then loaded some data into that, now I want to retrieve average rating of movies having more than 30 ratings.

I tried creating a view using query:

```
create view ratingcount as select movieid, count(rating) as num_of_ratings from u_data group by movieid;
```

and then used join query:

```
Select movieid, avg(rating) from u_data join ratingcount on u_data.movieid = ratingcount .movieid where num_of_ratings >30;
```

which is giving exception. please let me know how to retrieve required data?

Comment: Please reedit your `sql` as code.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by reedit sql as code

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
Select movieid, avg(rating) from u_data group by movieid having count(rating) > 30;
```

Comment: Thank you krish, but the query condition should be count(rating) > 30.

Comment: Please add some explanation why this works. What is the crucial difference to the query the Op gave in the question? In its current state, this is a low quality answer (and thus would be deleted).

Comment: Hi Jost, if you could provide optimized query please suggest. Thank you